# Entry URL Format - Parent + Children

Tags: templating, url

I created grouped category name projectCategory and assigned projects as the parent of design, 3d and art.

In project section (Channel) I have wrote `{projectCategory.first().slug}/{slug}`  and in categories (projectCategory) the top level is `{slug}` and nested categories `{parent.uri}/{slug}`.

Setup the field (projectCategory) so that I can assigned entry to selected category. So far

The result is not what I am hoping for at the moment sample.com/projects/mer-car-model is what generated. I was hoping that it should read sample.com/projects/3d/mer-car-model. I would appreciate some guidance how to achieve the result.

Comment: In your project channel settings could you try `{object.projectCategory.first().slug}/{slug}`?

Answer (score 1):

The above setting that I wrote is good until I forgot to change the limit number of selectable categories from 1 to 2 which solve my problem.  I think that was the problem for not showing the children due to limit to one select category. Now I can add two categories (The parent and child).